# how to customize materialize modal

Tags: html, css, materialize

i want modal to appear on the right end side of the screen with the given width and height. But the problem is, it is appearing in different way if I see it in different screens.

For example : In small screens the modal is half visible (the other half is not visible) and in large screens the modal is taking only 3/4th space.

Here is my HTML code for modal:

```css
div#myModal.modal.open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  top: 13vh !important;
  left: 129vh;
  width: 58vh;
  background-color: #37373b !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="valign-wrapper modal modalHeight" style="height:100%; overflow-x:hidden;">
  <div class="modal-content right">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Approval Form</h4>
      <button class="modal-close close dashboardClose" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="close()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body modalHeight">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you share the link of the framework you are using? because i tried importing materialize to this, but nothing shows. therefore better if you can show the link

Comment: using the viewport height for the `width` and `left` property seems unintended, `scaleX(1)` does just nothing

Comment: Below is the link of the framework i am using   http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Answer (score 0):

Mention top, left, width and height in percentage.
For my code the below modifications worked

```
div#myModal.modal.open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  top: 15.1% !important;
   left: 70% !important;
  width: 30% !important;
  background-color: #37373b !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```